# How capture the same capture group multiple times?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture every `name=value` pair with regex in a url query.

Lets say I have queries like this:

```
?lm=1403085628
?lm=1403085628&other=343323
?lm=1403085628&other=&second=34342
?lm=1403085628&=343243&second=34342
?lm=1403085628&other=343323&some=efsfs
?
?lm=1403085628&other=343323&&&wrong
```

If I try [this](http://regexr.com/3fa27): `^\?(?:([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\=[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)&?)*`

This capture the last occurrence only, for example `some=efsfs` for the third one.

But what I want is an array of key value pairs like this:

```
[
  'lm=1403085628', 
  'other=',
  'second=34342' 
]
```

How can I capture all occurrences of a capture group?

PS: I think this must have bee asked before but I cannot find any question, but maybe because I don't know the wording.

Comment: See  [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, but thats doesn't answer my question, I need them as an array, the answer in the linked question assume I know the name of the parameters.

Comment: Is there only one answer? See https://jsfiddle.net/99k4szcn/, just wrote using that post. There may be better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
var regex = /(?:[?&](.*?)=([^?&]+))/g

regex.exec(inputQuery);
```

This would return values in this manner:

```
["?lm=1403085628", "lm", "1403085628"]
```

Index 0 is the match, index 1 is the name and index 2 is the value. If you do this in a loop you can capture both name and values right away

```
var result;
var values = [];
do {
  values.push(result);
} while(result = regex.exec(queryInput))
```

Alternatively (no regex, more efficient), you can just use:

```
'?lm=1403085628&other=&second=34342'.slice(1).split('&')
// Results in : ["lm=1403085628", "other=", "second=34342"]
```

EDIT: JsFiddle demonstrating the slice / split method

```js
console.log('?lm=1403085628'.slice(1).split('&'));
console.log('?lm=1403085628&other=343323'.slice(1).split('&'));
console.log('?lm=1403085628&other=&second=34342'.slice(1).split('&'));
console.log('?lm=1403085628&=343243&second=34342'.slice(1).split('&'));
console.log('?lm=1403085628&other=343323&some=efsfs'.slice(1).split('&'));
console.log('?'.slice(1).split('&'));
console.log('?lm=1403085628&other=343323&&&wrong'.slice(1).split('&'));
```